# save state the list on page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, cookies

I have a script (JQuery) for drop-down list UL. How to remember the state of the list in a cookie and save state the list on page refresh? Any help much appreciated!

**Example on JSfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/77y7sqwr/

**Code below:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("li:has(ul:has(li))").prepend('<div class="drop"></div>');
    $(".ul-dropfree div.drop").click(function() {
        if ($(this).nextAll("ul").css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideDown(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "-22px 0"
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideUp(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "0 0"
            });
        }
    });
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("ul").slideUp(400).parents("li").children("div.drop").css({
        'background-position': "0 0"
    });
});
```

Comment: habe you read about javascript cookies?

Comment: @madalinivascu but I do not understand how to apply to this problem

Comment: Well you can make use of **[application cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)**

Comment: try html5 localstorage its very quick and easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something like cookie in javascript then you can go for localStorage.
localStorage provide you flexibility to store a value and access the value even after page refresh.

Use like below:
Save value to localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Get value from localStorage

```
var value = localStorage.getItem("key");
```